# Is it possible, or even a best practice to bundle state updates in React?

Tags: reactjs

This is a real code snippet from our codebase:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data && Array.isArray(data) && data.length !== 0) {
        setHasData(true)
        const firstRecord = data[0]
        if (firstRecord.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
            setHasKey(true)
        }
        if (firstRecord.hasOwnProperty('guid')) {
            setHasGuid(true)
        }
        if (firstRecord.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
            setHasOrder(true)
        }
        if (firstRecord.hasOwnProperty('slug')) {
            setHasSlug(true)
        }
    }
    else {
        setHasData(false)
    }
}, [data])
```

As you can see, we set 5 states one after the other.

I wonder if it's a possible, or even best practice at all, to somehow tell React to bundle these state changes all at once?

Comment: There is no best practice!!  Please read and contemplate ["No Best Practices"](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) and stop using that phrase in polite company.

Comment: @StephenC, read the first paragraphs and I have to completely disagree. With all respect, clean coding is a best practice. Choosing good readable names for variables is the best practice. There are absolute values in the realm of software development that any developer gets to after a couple of years.

Comment: OK.  So on whose authority do you claim it is best practice?   And what if the names are the result of an IDL -> source code translation which doesn't generate readable names (per your working definition of readable)?   Just about every so-called "best practice" has plausible exceptions ... which makes it literally NOT best practice.

Comment: It's the spirit, not the instances that makes the best practice. Noone can tell you to put your refrigerator in your kitchen. But almost all human beings put their refrigerators in their kitchens. You might choose not to do so. But there are unwritten reasons and universal agreements for this.

Comment: @StephenC, sure, I will read it and thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: My mother has a refrigerator in the garage.  For good reasons.  Let's face it, there are very few cases where unwritten "best practice" is actually universally the correct thing to do.  The only cases where best practices are actually a real thing is when they are set out by some organization with actual authority; e.g. https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/sites/default/files/content-files/2016-12/industry_engagement_forengineeering_-_summary_guidelines_as_at_aaee_conference.pdf.  Then they are best practice because the organization says so.  This does not apply in IT or in your kitchen.